# What is the biblical basis for Semi-Pelagianism?

Tags: soteriology, nature-of-man, free-will, heresy

Broadly speaking, Semi-Pelagianism is the idea that while we are born sinners, we are capable of seeking God without a supernatural "override" of our nature, such as that of Calvinism's Irresistible Grace or Arminianism's Prevenient Grace. Once God is sought, SP does not deny God's regenerative, renewing work in transforming us to be more Christlike; the emphasis is on the initial step.

Is there any positive argument from scripture to be made that this inherent capability exists, and we are not held back from even wanting to seek God until he sovereignly "unlocks" us?